# Unable build static library

Tags: ios, static-libraries, objective-c++

I am building a static library of github code https://github.com/jasenhuang/ASWBXml-c. I am able to build library successfully but when i am trying add in project getting an error. Below is the error log.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "std::string::end()
>   const", referenced from:
>         ASUtils::LowercaseString(std::string const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
>         ASUtils::UppercaseString(std::string const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)   "std::string::size() const",
>   referenced from:
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::EncodeOpaque(std::string&, std::vector >&) in
>   libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::EncodeString(std::string&, std::vector >&) in
>   libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASUtils::LowercaseString(std::string const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
>         ASUtils::UppercaseString(std::string const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)   "std::string::begin() const",
>   referenced from:
>         ASUtils::LowercaseString(std::string const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
>         ASUtils::UppercaseString(std::string const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)   "std::string::c_str() const",
>   referenced from:
>         +[FMWbxml wb2xml:] in libASWBXMLHelper.a(FMWbxml.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::LoadBytes(unsigned char*, unsigned int) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::LoadXml(std::string const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::LoadXmlFromFile(std::string const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::SetCodePageByXmlns(std::string&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)   "std::string::empty() const",
>   referenced from:
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::LoadBytes(unsigned char*, unsigned int) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::SetCodePageByXmlns(std::string&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)   "std::string::compare(char const*)
>   const", referenced from:
>         bool std::operator==, std::allocator >(std::basic_string,
>   std::allocator > const&, char const*) in
>   libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)   "std::string::compare(std::string
>   const&) const", referenced from:
>         bool std::operator==, std::allocator >(std::basic_string,
>   std::allocator > const&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&) in
>   libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         bool std::operator<, std::allocator >(std::basic_string,
>   std::allocator > const&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&) in
>   libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)   "std::basic_ios >::operator void*() const", referenced from:
>         ASUtils::Split(std::string const&, char, std::vector >&) in
>   libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)   "std::allocator::allocator()",
>   referenced from:
>         +[FMWbxml xml2wb:] in libASWBXMLHelper.a(FMWbxml.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitAirSyncPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitContactsPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitEmailPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitCalendarPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitMovePage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitItemEstimatePage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ...   "std::allocator::~allocator()", referenced from:
>         +[FMWbxml xml2wb:] in libASWBXMLHelper.a(FMWbxml.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitAirSyncPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitContactsPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitEmailPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitCalendarPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitMovePage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitItemEstimatePage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ...   "std::string::begin()", referenced from:
>         ASUtils::LowercaseString(std::string const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
>         ASUtils::UppercaseString(std::string const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)   "std::string::resize(unsigned long)",
>   referenced from:
>         ASUtils::LowercaseString(std::string const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
>         ASUtils::UppercaseString(std::string const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)   "std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(char
>   const*, std::allocator const&)", referenced from:
>         +[FMWbxml xml2wb:] in libASWBXMLHelper.a(FMWbxml.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitAirSyncPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitContactsPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitEmailPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitCalendarPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitMovePage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitItemEstimatePage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ...   "std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string(std::string const&)", referenced
>   from:
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::LoadBytes(unsigned char*, unsigned int) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::EncodeNode(TiXmlElement*, std::vector >&) in
>   libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         __gnu_cxx::new_allocator::construct(std::string*, std::string const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
>         std::vector >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, std::string
>   const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
>         void std::_Construct(std::string*, std::string const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXMLCodePage::AddToken(char, std::string) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXMLCodePage::GetTag(char) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)
>         ...   "std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string()", referenced from:
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::EncodeNode(TiXmlElement*, std::vector >&) in
>   libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASWBXML::CASWBXML::ParseXmlnsAttributes(TiXmlElement*) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
>         ASUtils::LowercaseString(std::string const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
>         ASUtils::UppercaseString(std::string const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
>         ASUtils::Split(std::string const&, char, std::vector >&) in
>   libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
>         std::map, std::allocator > >::operator[](char
>   const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)
>   "std::basic_string, std::allocator
>
> > ::~basic_string()", referenced from:
> >           +[FMWbxml xml2wb:] in libASWBXMLHelper.a(FMWbxml.o)
> >           +[FMWbxml wb2xml:] in libASWBXMLHelper.a(FMWbxml.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitAirSyncPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitContactsPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitEmailPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitCalendarPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitMovePage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ...   "std::string::operator=(char const*)", referenced from:
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitAirSyncPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitContactsPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitEmailPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitAirNotifyPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitCalendarPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitMovePage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitItemEstimatePage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ...   "std::string::operator=(std::string const&)", referenced from:
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::EncodeNode(TiXmlElement*, std::vector >&) in
> >     libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::ParseXmlnsAttributes(TiXmlElement*) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           std::vector >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, std::string
> >     const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
> >           std::string* std::__copy_backward::__copy_b(std::string*, std::string*, std::string*) in
> >     libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)   "std::string::operator[](unsigned
> >     long)", referenced from:
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::EncodeOpaque(std::string&, std::vector >&) in
> >     libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::EncodeString(std::string&, std::vector >&) in
> >     libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)   "std::string::operator+=(char)",
> >     referenced from:
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXMLByteQueue::DequeueString() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLByteQueue.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXMLByteQueue::DequeueString(int) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLByteQueue.o)
> >     "std::basic_stringstream,
> >     std::allocator >::basic_stringstream(std::string const&,
> >     std::_Ios_Openmode)", referenced from:
> >           ASUtils::Split(std::string const&, char, std::vector >&) in
> >     libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)   "std::basic_stringstream, std::allocator
> >     ::~basic_stringstream()", referenced from:
> >           ASUtils::Split(std::string const&, char, std::vector >&) in
> >     libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)   "std::ios_base::Init::Init()",
> >     referenced from:
> >           ___cxx_global_var_init in libASWBXMLHelper.a(FMWbxml.o)
> >           ___cxx_global_var_init in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ___cxx_global_var_init in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
> >           ___cxx_global_var_init in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)
> >           ___cxx_global_var_init in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLByteQueue.o)   "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
> >           ___cxx_global_var_init in libASWBXMLHelper.a(FMWbxml.o)
> >           ___cxx_global_var_init in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ___cxx_global_var_init in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
> >           ___cxx_global_var_init in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)
> >           ___cxx_global_var_init in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLByteQueue.o)   "std::__throw_bad_alloc()", referenced from:
> >           __gnu_cxx::new_allocator::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           __gnu_cxx::new_allocator::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           __gnu_cxx::new_allocator::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
> >           __gnu_cxx::new_allocator > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) in
> >     libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)
> >           __gnu_cxx::new_allocator > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) in
> >     libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)
> >           __gnu_cxx::new_allocator::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLByteQueue.o)
> >           __gnu_cxx::new_allocator::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLByteQueue.o)
> >           ...   "std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)", referenced from:
> >           std::_Rb_tree_iterator >::operator--() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)
> >           std::_Rb_tree_iterator >::operator--() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)   "std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)", referenced from:
> >           std::_Rb_tree_iterator >::operator++() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)
> >           std::_Rb_tree_iterator >::operator++() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)   "std::__throw_length_error(char const*)", referenced from:
> >           std::vector >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, unsigned
> >     char const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           std::vector
> >     ::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >,
> >     ASWBXML::CASWBXMLCodePage* const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           std::vector >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, std::string
> >     const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
> >     "std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*,
> >     std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)", referenced from:
> >           std::_Rb_tree, std::_Select1st >, std::less,
> >     std::allocator >
> >     ::_M_insert(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::pair const&) in
> >     libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)
> >           std::_Rb_tree, std::_Select1st >,
> >     std::less, std::allocator > >::_M_insert(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*,
> >     std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::pair const&)
> >     in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)   "std::basic_istream >& std::getline,
> >     std::allocator >(std::basic_istream
> >     &, std::basic_string, std::allocator >&, char)", referenced from:
> >           ASUtils::Split(std::string const&, char, std::vector >&) in
> >     libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)   "std::terminate()", referenced from:
> >           ___clang_call_terminate in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ___clang_call_terminate in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinystr.o)
> >           ___clang_call_terminate in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           ___clang_call_terminate in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
> >           ___clang_call_terminate in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)
> >           ___clang_call_terminate in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLByteQueue.o)
> >           ___clang_call_terminate in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxmlparser.o)
> >           ...   "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info", referenced from:
> >           typeinfo for TiXmlVisitor in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           typeinfo for TiXmlBase in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           typeinfo for TiXmlVisitor in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           typeinfo for TiXmlBase in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxmlparser.o)   NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual
> >     member function has no definition.   "vtable for
> >     __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info", referenced from:
> >           typeinfo for TiXmlNode in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           typeinfo for TiXmlComment in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           typeinfo for TiXmlText in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           typeinfo for TiXmlDeclaration in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           typeinfo for TiXmlUnknown in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           typeinfo for TiXmlPrinter in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           typeinfo for TiXmlElement in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           ...   NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.   "operator
> >     delete", referenced from:
> >           TiXmlString::quit() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           TiXmlString::quit() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinystr.o)
> >           TiXmlDocument::LoadFile(__sFILE*, TiXmlEncoding) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           TiXmlString::quit() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           TiXmlString::quit() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxmlparser.o)   "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
> >           +[FMWbxml xml2wb:] in libASWBXMLHelper.a(FMWbxml.o)
> >           +[FMWbxml wb2xml:] in libASWBXMLHelper.a(FMWbxml.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::~CASWBXML() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitAirSyncPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitContactsPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitEmailPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitAirNotifyPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ...   "operator new[](unsigned long)", referenced from:
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::GetBytes(unsigned char**, unsigned int*) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           TiXmlString::init(unsigned long, unsigned long) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           TiXmlString::init(unsigned long, unsigned long) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinystr.o)
> >           TiXmlDocument::LoadFile(__sFILE*, TiXmlEncoding) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           TiXmlString::init(unsigned long, unsigned long) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           TiXmlString::init(unsigned long, unsigned long) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxmlparser.o)   "operator new(unsigned long)",
> >     referenced from:
> >           +[FMWbxml xml2wb:] in libASWBXMLHelper.a(FMWbxml.o)
> >           +[FMWbxml wb2xml:] in libASWBXMLHelper.a(FMWbxml.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitAirSyncPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitContactsPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitEmailPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitAirNotifyPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::InitCalendarPage() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ...   "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
> >           std::vector >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, unsigned
> >     char const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ___clang_call_terminate in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           std::vector
> >     ::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >,
> >     ASWBXML::CASWBXMLCodePage* const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ___clang_call_terminate in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinystr.o)
> >           ___clang_call_terminate in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           std::vector >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, std::string
> >     const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
> >           ___clang_call_terminate in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
> >           ...   "___cxa_call_unexpected", referenced from:
> >           ASWBXML::CASWBXML::~CASWBXML() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           std::vector >::~vector() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           std::_Vector_base >::~_Vector_base() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           std::vector >::~vector() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           std::_Vector_base >::~_Vector_base() in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           std::vector >::~vector() in
> >     libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           std::_Vector_base >::~_Vector_base() in
> >     libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           ...   "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
> >           std::vector >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, unsigned
> >     char const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           std::vector
> >     ::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >,
> >     ASWBXML::CASWBXMLCodePage* const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           std::vector >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, std::string
> >     const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
> >           std::string* std::__uninitialized_copy_aux(std::string*, std::string*, std::string*,
> >     std::__false_type) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
> >           std::_Rb_tree, std::_Select1st >, std::less,
> >     std::allocator >
> >     ::_M_create_node(std::pair const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)
> >           std::_Rb_tree, std::_Select1st >,
> >     std::less, std::allocator > >::_M_create_node(std::pair const&)
> >     in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)
> >           std::deque >::_M_push_back_aux(unsigned char const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLByteQueue.o)
> >           ...   "___cxa_pure_virtual", referenced from:
> >           vtable for TiXmlNode in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           vtable for TiXmlBase in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           vtable for TiXmlBase in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxmlparser.o)   "___cxa_rethrow", referenced from:
> >           std::vector >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, unsigned
> >     char const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           std::vector
> >     ::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >,
> >     ASWBXML::CASWBXMLCodePage* const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           std::vector >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, std::string
> >     const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
> >           std::string* std::__uninitialized_copy_aux(std::string*, std::string*, std::string*,
> >     std::__false_type) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
> >           std::_Rb_tree, std::_Select1st >, std::less,
> >     std::allocator >
> >     ::_M_create_node(std::pair const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)
> >           std::_Rb_tree, std::_Select1st >,
> >     std::less, std::allocator > >::_M_create_node(std::pair const&)
> >     in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)
> >           std::deque >::_M_push_back_aux(unsigned char const&) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLByteQueue.o)
> >           ...   "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
> >           Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(FMWbxml.o)
> >           Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXML.o)
> >           Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinystr.o)
> >           Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(tinyxml.o)
> >           Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASUtils.o)
> >           Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLCodepage.o)
> >           Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in libASWBXMLHelper.a(ASWBXMLByteQueue.o)
> >           ... ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

I had tried to change c++ compiler type for Xcode project but no luck.

Comment: Do you get errors after just adding the library, or after importing a header from library's headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally able to solve it. I need to set

> -lstdc++

in **other linker flag** in library project.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to build and combine static library for various architectures and combine them using `lipo`. See the Universal Binaries Section in following [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial.).

EDIT:
For iOS Simulator(64-bit) use `-sdk iphonesimulator -arch x86_64`